# Neovim doesn't open previously unopen file in horizontal split

Tags: neovim, buffers, save

In classic Vi/Vim when I opened a previously unopened file with ctrlp, NERDTree, etc. *and* the current file/buffer was unsaved, it would open the new file in a horizontal split.

After switching to Neovim, this functionality worked.  Then after installing telescope.nvim this behavior ceased.  I uninstalled telescope and the desired behavior began again until here in the last day or so.

Now if I don't to save a file and open a new one, then `:q` I get an error about an unsaved buffer.  The previous horizontal split behavior was preferable.  How do I get this back? I have included a link to my dotfiles which includes my original `.vimrc` for vim classic and my lua config for Neovim.

Edit/Update:

A simple .vimrc with

```
set nocompatible
```

produces this behavior.  However an larger init.vim or init.lua with supress this behavior.  I'm confused

Comment: Would it be possible for you to provide the simplest `init.vim` or `init.lua` to reproduce the problem? It would also help to have a step by step description of the "old" behavior on Vim with again the simplest `vimrc` file. I must admit that I don't know how you get the "old" behavior (some screenshot could help too) :-|.

Comment: I update the question with the contents of a minimal .vimrc.  Open a file with :edit, make a change _but do not `:w`_   Then `:edit` another file or ``:Ex` to open netrw and you'll see the unsaved buffer preserved and the new file/netrw opened in a split

Comment: I'm afraid I can't reproduce the behavior (if `:set hidden?` is set no `nohidden` I can open a new buffer in the main split if the main split buffer is not saved). With a simple `vimrc` you suggest the `:Explore` command is not available). I'm afraid we need more information about the minimal `vimrc` you are using :-|

Comment: just tested, the same content in t init.lua does not do the same for nvim.  I'm confused as to how it was working in the first place

Comment: The `:Sexplore` let you open the new buffer in a new horizontal split. Maybe `:Explore` as been replaced by `:Sexplore` in your "old" system at least when the current buffer was not saved.

Comment: Or `:split` is replacing `:edit`.

Comment: is there a way I can alias this or something in my nvim config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much experimentation, classic vim sets `nohidden` by default.  Neovim sets `hidden` by default.

a `set nohidden` or lua equivalent fixed the issue.

Comment: I believe this is only true for NERDTree not for `:e` or `:Explore`. Do you confirm? If so maybe could you adapt your question.

Comment: I confirmed for `:edit`, and `Ex`.  I guess I should also do thisd for ctrlp and/or telescope as that is where I saw the behavior change; after installing telescope while trying to enable ThePrimegen/harpoon

Comment: Could your precise what you mean by I confirm for `:edit` and `:Ex`? Do you mean that `:edit` and `:Ex` have the same behavior as `:NERDTree` (opening a split when the current buffer is modified and the `hidden` option is not set)? I my tests it is not the case. Maybe NERDTree is hijacking `Ex`?

Comment: A typically useful way to debug these things is to apply [How to debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604), though in this case you'd also want to include things from the output of `:set` and from https://neovim.io/doc/user/vim_diff.html#vim-differences

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt I'm seeing the same behavior between `:edit`, `:Ex`, ctrl-p, and NERDTree.

However when I install telescope, instead of opening a split like the others above, it opens the new buffer in the background, and the unsaved file remains in the current unsplit window.  Working on that bit now.

Comment: Interesting. I can't reproduce that behavior myself at least for `:edit` (but I do with `:Explore`,  NERDTree or CtrlP)

Comment: Maybe could you accept your own answer. It allow the question to rest :-)

Answer (score 0):

The following code introduces the `Ex` command

```
function! Explore()
  if !&hidden && getbufinfo(bufnr('%'))[0].changed
    Sexplore
  else
    Explore
  endif
endfunction

command! Ex call Explore()
```

This new `Ex` command triggers `:Sexplore` if:

- The current buffer is modified and
- The `hidden` option is off

and `:Explore` otherwise.